# Existem vantagens em se utilizar "use function" para funções nativas do PHP?

Tags: php

Quando trabalhado com *namespaces*, é normal vermos a utilização do `use` para importar classes externas ao escopo local:

```
namespace Foo;

use Bar\Classe;
use DateTime;
```

Também é possível fazer o mesmo com funções:

```
namespace Foo;

use function Bar\funcao_qualquer;
use function is_null;
```

Verificando a [documentação acerca da resolução de nomes](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.rules.php) é possível constatar que quando o nome a ser importado refere-se à uma função e essa não existe no *namespace* atual, o nome será resolvido para o escopo global.

> For unqualified names, if no import rule applies and the name refers to a function or constant and the code is outside the global namespace, the name is resolved at runtime. Assuming the code is in namespace `A\B`, here is how a call to function `foo()` is resolved:
>
> 1. It looks for a function from the current namespace: `A\B\foo()`.
> 2. It tries to find and call the global function `foo()`.

Visto que uma função nativa sempre será resolvida até o escopo global naturalmente, existe alguma vantagem em importá-la via `use`? Para constantes globais a ideia é a mesma?

Vi fazerem isso na implementação do [Zend Diactoros](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-diactoros/blob/master/src/Stream.php) em que há:

```
use function array_key_exists;
use function fclose;
use function feof;
use function fopen;
use function fread;
use function fseek;
use function fstat;
use function ftell;
use function fwrite;
use function get_resource_type;
use function is_int;
use function is_resource;
use function is_string;
use function restore_error_handler;
use function set_error_handler;
use function stream_get_contents;
use function stream_get_meta_data;
use function strstr;

use const E_WARNING;
use const SEEK_SET;
```

Comment: Você sabe algo sobre isso que não é óbvio ou documentado? Me parece que não tem vantagem porque está trazendo pro escopo atual algo que já está no escopo atual. Mas poderia ser útil por algum problema de implementação mulambenta de resolução :)

Comment: @Maniero A única justificativa que percebi foi para evitar que essas funções sejam reescritas dentro do *namespace*, mas não sei se seria somente isso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Existe vantagem** em usar a diretiva `use` em funções e globais nativas dentro de um `namespace`. Há uma *redução de tempo gasto em processamento* que, considerando execuções massivas em aplicações de carga, fazem diferença. Não faz diferença para nossos sites pessoais cheios de teias de aranha.. Mas ganho é ganho!

---

**Toon Verwerft**, no final de 2016, criou um [artigo](https://veewee.github.io/blog/optimizing-php-performance-by-fq-function-calls/) (em inglês) que sintetiza uma discussão dessa época sobre o caso e que foi [iniciada no Twitter](https://twitter.com/Ocramius/status/811504929357660160) (em inglês). No artigo, Verwerft também detalha o *benchmark* que fez e motivo para a diferença: internamente o PHP verifica primeiro se existe uma função no `namespace` atual e só depois no `global` por meio do *opcode* `INIT_NS_FCALL_BY_NAME`. Há custo de processamento.

Segundo os testes de Verwerft, **a maneira de ganhar processamento é fazer chamadas de funções globais de forma completamente qualificadas (CQ)** (*fully qualified (FQ)*). Uma chamada de função global completamente qualificada elimina o *opcode* `INIT_NS_FCALL_BY_NAME`. Nos testes, houve ganho de 2.26% em relação a chamada de funções globais não completamente qualificadas (NCQ) (*non-fully qualified (Non-FQ)*) - que são as chamadas normais.

Existem duas formas de deixar as globais completamente qualificadas:

```
<?php

// Método 1
namespace baz;
\foo();

// Método 2
namespace baz;
use function foo;
foo();

?>
```

No final do artigo, há uma listagem de soluções da comunidade feita por Verwerft. Da lista, listo algumas:

- [Autocompletar para funções CQ no PHPStorm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34446);
- [fqn-check](https://github.com/kelunik/fqn-check), [PHP BackSlasher](https://github.com/nilportugues/php-backslasher): ferramentas CLI que checam os arquivos por chamadas de funções CQ;